# How to return single value from list after filter using JSON Path extractor?

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

Using the below example test url for reference i want to return only one value from the result.

[http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book[?(@.price%20%3C=%20$[%27expensive%27])]](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book%5B?(@.price%20%3C=%20$%5B%27expensive%27%5D)%5D)

Tried by applying `[:1]` at the end it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is just playing with "Match No" field of the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

[image]

- `-1` - you will get both matches

  ```
   inexpensive_1={"category":"reference","title":"Sayings of the Century","author":"Nigel Rees","price":8.95}
   inexpensive_2={"category":"fiction","title":"Moby Dick","author":"Herman Melville","price":8.99,"isbn":"0-553-21311-3"}
   inexpensive_matchNr=2
  ```
- `1` - you will get first match

  ```
   inexpensive={"category":"reference","title":"Sayings of the Century","author":"Nigel Rees","price":8.95}
  ```
- `2` - you will get second match:

  ```
   inexpensive={"category":"fiction","title":"Moby Dick","author":"Herman Melville","price":8.99,"isbn":"0-553-21311-3"}
  ```
- `0` - you will get random match

Or alternatively you can go for [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) which has [pipe expressions](https://jmespath.org/proposals/pipes.html):

```
store.book[?price<`10`] | [0]
```

[image]